# 'Docker restart' from within Jenkins

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

Is there somewhere in jenkins 'job configuration' where I can restart docker?

Currently docker is sitting on a server within the organisation and every now and then I have to restart it locally on my pc:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=[serverName]
docker restart [containerId]
```

After this, I kick off a Jenkins job (maven project) that runs tests within the above container

Is there a way, perhaps in the Jenkins job configuration, where I can run the above commands and how? So that I don't have to do it locally

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky but you can put a shell script on the Docker box, then call it over ssh from the Jenkins job as a command.

See [here](https://coderwall.com/p/cdzktg/run-one-command-through-ssh-connection-and-exit) for examples of remote ssh commands.

You will have to set up keys for the user that runs the command.